# Identify process using a specific port

Tags: macos, ports

I understand that similar questions have been already asked, but i still cant get around this issue..

I am trying to instantiate a docker container that will require port binding on 8443 on the host's port, but i get below error

```
Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8443 failed: port is already allocated.
```

When i try to diagnose the port in use

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any process associated with this port.

[image]

also tried lsof -i

[image]

How can i go about diagnosing this port. I am currently on mac

Updated with lsof without filters
[image]

Comment: Is it possible allocated by the process who uses UDP? Try `netstat -tunlp`

Comment: netstat -tunl | grep 8443   giving no results.  -p is for protocol and not process for mac . so i dropped this flag. Its a tcp port as netstat -tanp tcp | grep 8443 is returning value as stated in my question.

Comment: Most probably you have an old instance of you same application running on the port. Just kill the older one and it will be fine. If you can't kill it, it means that it was started by another user on the same machine (possible superuser).

Comment: @TheChetan I have restarted my macbook couple of times already.but this tcp port spawns on boot. I was initializing my application for the first time and it failed to start as it could not acquire the port. Moreover there is no process associate with this port so i cannot kill it.  ps -ef | grep 8443 does not return anything.. but netstat -tan | grep 8443 does return a listening activity.

Comment: Also you are using `lsof` wrongly here, the syntax is `lsof -i: 8443`

Comment: Is this on a docker machine? My bad the command is `lsof -i :3000`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155642/discussion-between-dhirendra-khanka-and-thechetan).

Comment: As pointed out by @TheChetan ,the ports in question is listed in the following link as Mac OSX Server. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944. I am not sure if there is technical answer to this question, but in the meantime, i can accept this for an answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @DhirendraKhanka, SO is a site based on good will. If you use a command on Mac, don't tag the question `linux`. If you do, and get a Linux answer, don't downvote the answer. If you do downvote an answer, do leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh i dont know how you concluded that the person down voting your answer is the post owner himself. About your suggestion on tagging the post under Linux, i did check for available tags and mac osX is not available i think.

Comment: @DhirendraKhanka in the spirit of sharing, I've fixed the tag for you.

Answer (score -1):

`netstat` finds out which process holds a specific port by going over the `/proc` pseudo file system and querying the process' internal state. For obvious reasons, you cannot query a process' internal state of a process that isn't yours unless you are `root`. Judging from your prompt starting with `$`, you are not running `netstat` as root.

Re-run the command as root, and the process should appear.